# Are A. Malcev's conditions first order?

Tags: model-theory

There is a Russian paper by A. Malcev written in 1939 that give infinitely many jointly necessary and sufficient conditions for a (not necessarily commutative) monoid to be embeddable. Are those conditions first-order? If yes, this would answer my question of whether group-embeddable monoids are an elementary class.

Comment: Can you tell us what those conditions are? (I don't have access to a copy of the paper.)

Comment: I'm not sure why this was put on hold.  Malcev's conditions are quite famous, and also fairly difficult to state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes -- see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6tbuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA268).  For example, the first three conditions are:

1. $(\forall a,b,c,c')(ac=ac' \Rightarrow bc'=bc')$.
2. $(\forall a,a',b,c)(ab=a'b \Rightarrow ac=a'c)$.
3. $(\forall a,a',b,b',c,c',d,d')(ab=cd \land ab'=cd'\land a'b'=c'd' \Rightarrow a'b=c'd)$.